# Как отслеживать нажатие клавиши в qtextedit?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Нужно что бы при нажатии ентера и фокусе на поле для ввода происходило какое то действие, сделал через eventFilter но текст вводится очень медленно.

```
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Type.KeyPress:
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key.Key_Return:
            print('Enter pressed')
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: 1. пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] .  2. Если ответы, которые вам предоставляют, решают вашу проблему, то не забудьте пометить их как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

```
def keyPressEvent(self, obj, event):
    if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key.Key_Return and obj.hasFocus():
        print('success')
```

не уверен, что работает т.к. не проверял